# Check if table data has changed?

Tags: sql

I am pulling the data from several tables and then passing the data to a long running process.  I would like to be able to record what data was used for the process and then query the database to check if any of the tables have changed since the process was last run.

Is there a method of solving this problem that should work across all sql databases?

One possible solution that I've thought of is having a separate table that is only used for keeping track of whether the data has changed since the process was run.  The table contains a "stale" flag.  When I start running the process, stale is set to false. If any creation, update, or deletion occurs in any of the tables on which the operation depends, I set stale to true. Is this a valid solution?  Are there better solutions?

One concern with my solution is situations like this:

One user starts inserting a new row into one of the tables. Stale gets set to true, but the new row has not actually been added yet. Another user has simultaneously started the long running process, pulling the data from the tables and setting the flag to false. The row is finally added. Now the data used for the process is out of date but the flag indicates it is not stale. Would transactions be able to solve this problem?

**EDIT:**

This is some SQL for my idea. Not sure if it works, but just to give you a better idea of what I was thinking:

```
# First transaction reads the data and sets the flag to false
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
  UPDATE flag SET stale = false
  SELECT * FROM DATATABLE  
COMMIT TRANSACTION

# Second transaction updates the data and sets the flag to true
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
  UPDATE data SET val = 15 WHERE ID = 10
  UPDATE flag SET stale = true
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

I do not have much experience with transactions or handwriting xml, so there are probably issues with this. From what I understand two serializable transactions can not be interleaved. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Is there a way to accomplish this with only the first transaction? The process will be run rarely, but the updates to the data table will occur more frequently, so it would be nice to not lock up the data table when performing updates.

Also, is the `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION` syntax specific to MS?

Comment: Don't think transactions will do you any good here.  I don't think you can manage something like this on the database side.  Maybe you could have a "queue" table where all the requests go, and a process that handles them one at a time, something like that.

Comment: I think what you need to do is to optimize the query that is touching the table and use the OUTPUT statement. This way you can track what is going on.

Comment: you pass all the data in all the tables to the *long running process*? and the process holds that data where? in memory? what size of data are we talking about? kb/mb/gb? ... *work across all sql databases* ... how broad is all?

Comment: @inquisitive The query that gets the data for the process joins two tables. Pretty much every record from one of the tables will be sent to the process along with selected data from the other. Yes, right now the process holds all the data in memory. I would expect to be passing at most a thousand objects to the process, each with a handful of integer fields. Right now the size of the data does not concern me too much, but I would appreciate suggestions for making this more scalable.

Comment: @inquisitive It doesn't have to work across all SQL databases, but the more general the technique the better. It is fine if a few syntax changes are needed, but I would prefer not to use a technique that is very specific to Postgres, Microsoft or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stale flag will probably work, but a timestamp would be better since it provides more metadata about the age of the records which could be used to tune your queries, e.g., only pull data that is over 5 minutes old.

To address your concern about inserting a row at the same time a query is run, transactions with an appropriate isolation level will help.  For row inserts, updates, and selects,  at least use a transaction with an isolation level that prevents dirty reads so that no other connections can see the updated data until the transaction is committed.

If you are strongly concerned about the case where an update happens at the same time as a record pull, you could use the REPEATABLE READ or even SERIALIZABLE isolation levels, but this will slow DB access down.

Your SQLServer sampled should work.  For alternate databases, Here's an example that works in PostGres:

**Transaction 1**

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
-- run queries that update the tables, then set last_updated column
UPDATE sometable SET last_updatee = now() WHERE id = 1;;
COMMIT;
```

**Transaction 2**

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
-- select data from tables, then set last_queried column
UPDATE sometable SET last_queried = now() WHERE id = 1;
COMMIT;
```

If transaction 1 starts, and then transaction 2 starts before transaction 1 has completed, transaction 2 will block during on the update, and then will throw an error when transaction 1 is committed.  If transaction 2 starts first, and transaction 1 starts before that has finished, then transaction 1 will error.   Your application code or process should be able to handle those errors.

Other databases use similar syntax - MySQL (with InnoDB plugin) requires you to set the isolation level before you start the transaction.

Comment: In (Microsoft) Sql a timestamp is a monotonically increasing bigint which is (almost) unique across a database.  It can't be used to work out "data that is over 5 minutes old" - just the order that rows have been updated - but it would still be the way I would solve OPs problem in a Microsoft environment.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, please see my edits in the original post. Not sure if what I am doing makes any sense.

Comment: @dav1dsm1th Could you elaborate on how I would use timestamps for this? Would I just get the max timestamp from the time_updated and time_created columns (if I had those)? How would this cover deletions? I don't really care about deletions at this point but I am curious. Also, I guess this would solve the timing issue because I would get the timestamp from the records I have loaded into memory, rather than performing another read. If I got the timestamps using a separate aggregate query than I would face the same problem.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Every table that needed tracking would need a timestamp column.  As you kick off the long running process - you would add a row which would give you a high water mark for the timestamp of included data.  Before the next run, you can recognise rows which need to be recalculated if their timestamp is higher than your high water mark.  Deletes cannot be recognised using this technique (but you could do something clever in a trigger I suppose).  MS spotted this as a problem and - since SQL2008 - have change tracking available http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933994(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @mushroom what you propose should work. I added PostGres examples that are very similar to your transactions.