# Detecting if model data has changed since a long-running process was last run?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am combining data from several models and then passing the data to a long running process. I would like to be able to record what data was used for the process and then query the database to check if any of the tables have changed since the process was last run.

For example, one contoller action kicks off the process and records the state of the models at the time it started. Another controller action is used to determine whether the data has changed since the last time the process ran.

Does anyone have a solution for this type of problem?

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20027247/check-if-table-data-has-changed) for an SQL-centric version of the question. Now I am trying to figure out how I could take care of this without handwriting SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/rails/rails-observers

Check out the section `Action Controller Sweeper`. Might involve some fair bit of work but might be worth it in the end.

Note: Observers are in the core of rails 3.x The gem is only for 4.x and up. But the documentation might be helpful anyway.

Comment: Any idea why they were removed from the core?

Comment: Yup! The sweepers are way to expire caches manually. It is very common to overlook some or the other scenario which leads to stale data. Rails 4 focusses on versioned caches. Read more at: http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3113-how-key-based-cache-expiration-works